# Condition in components list in WIX

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer

Is there any way to check file existence during installation. My idea is to implement some thing like this:

`1. Install "file1.txt"
2. if FileExists("file2.txt")
      Install "file3.txt"
   else
      Install "file4.txt"
3. Install "file5.txt"`

How can it be done using wix?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [file search](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/filesearch.html) to check if file2 exists. ([Example](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/files_and_registry/check_the_version_number.html))
The result of the search is stored in a property.

Use this property to [condition the component](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/conditional-component-installation-td687768.html) the hold the file3 and file4.

Comment: I tried everything, but it doesn't work... Please can you look through https://pastebin.com/mtDkqrXa

Comment: @Edward When is property INSTALLFOLDER set? FileSearch runs very early in the InstallExecuteSequence so most properties will not be available.